# Unable To Capture The Last City in a Region?

Tags: mount-and-blade-warband

I recently picked up a copy of Mount & Blade: Warband and am still fairly new. I have managed to capture almost all of a region on the Campaign map, but I am unable to besiege the last city. What am I doing wrong? Do I need to somehow overthrow the king, or is there some other, more obvious way that I simply haven't noticed?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "can't capture"? You don't have the option to besiege when you see the town menu? Or what?

Comment: @Baskakov_Dmitriy That's exactly what's wrong. I will go to the city but I will not have the option to besiege.

Comment: Are you at war with the kingdom?

Comment: It's possible that you can't besiege that town because that town is already being besieged by another faction.

Comment: @Gaunt Then there would be an option "Join the next assault"

Comment: @Baskakov_Dmitriy that will only happen if they are fighting(if it's being sieged, then it's just waiting for the food to run out)

Answer (score 1):

Without more information it's hard to say what the issue is but there are three likely culprits:

**The town is already under siege from allies or and independent faction.**
These allies arrived and initiated a siege before you did. The game won't allow you to start a siege because one is already underway! If you notice armies congregated outside of the city try waiting a day and see if they mount an attack on their own. If they lead an assault, you'll be able to join the attack as soon as it starts.

**You've made peace with the enemy faction**
It's possible you agreed to a truce while you weren't paying attention. If you haven't played for a few days it's possible you made an agreement with the opposing king  and forgot about it. For whatever reason, the hostilities are now over and you aren't able to besiege the city. Try declaring war again and see if that allows you to continue your conquests.

**The city was conquered by a neutral third party**
I've found that under certain conditions the color schemes of the Kingdom of Swadia and Kherigate Khanate can look similar. Despite one faction using orange text and the other using purple, when  fully zoomed out of the world map the text appears almost an identical white. If your computer monitor or television screen isn't properly calibrated then you may be unintentionally trying to attack a faction you aren't at war with. If you don't have a negative reputation with a faction you shouldn't be take a hostile action against them. In other words, you wouldn't see the option to initiate a siege.